# npm - fix vulnerable dependency in package-lock.json

Tags: npm

Github is alerting a vulnerability with the message:

> Upgrade js-yaml to version 3.13.1 or later. For example:
>
> ```
> "dependencies": {
>   "js-yaml": ">=3.13.1"
> }
> ```

I have tried the following to update js-yaml to no avail.

1. Uninstall all node modules. `npm install` and `npm install js-yaml` to add js-yaml 3.13.1 to package.json
2. Same as above but deleted node-modules folder instead of `npm uninstall`
3. `npm install {dependency}` Where `dependency` is each package that relies on js-yaml. This works for some, but not all of the dependencies in my packag-lock.json
4. `npm audit fix` which reports that reports `fixed 0 of 8 vulnerabilities in 10114 scanned packages. 8 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated`

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "blackfynn-csv-exporter",
  "version": "1.1.7",
  "description": "View Timeseries data stored on Blackfynn and export it to csv for OpenCOR",
  "main": "build/build.min.js",
  "files": [
    "package.json",
    "LICENSE",
    "README.md",
    "css",
    "js",
    "fonts",
    "index.html",
    "build/build.js",
    "build/build.min.js",
    "webpack.config.js"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=none",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/tehsurfer/blackfynn-csv-exporter"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "OpenCOR",
    "Blackfynn",
    "data",
    "export"
  ],
  "author": "Jesse Khorasanee <jessekhorasanee@gmail.com>",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/tehsurfer/blackfynn-csv-exporter/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/tehsurfer/blackfynn-csv-exporter",
  "devDependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "ify-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "plotly.js": "^1.48.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1",
    "standard": "^12.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-jquery-ui": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "papaparse": "^4.6.3"
  }
}
```

#### package-lock.json (snippet)

```
{
  "name": "blackfynn-csv-exporter",
  "version": "1.0.14",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "gray-matter": {
        "version": "3.1.1",
        "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/gray-matter/-/gray-matter-3.1.1.tgz",
        "integrity": "sha512-nZ1qjLmayEv0/wt3sHig7I0s3/sJO0dkAaKYQ5YAOApUtYEOonXSFdWvL1khvnZMTvov4UufkqlFsilPnejEXA==",
        "dev": true,
        "requires": {
            "extend-shallow": "^2.0.1",
            "js-yaml": "^3.10.0",
            "kind-of": "^5.0.2",
            "strip-bom-string": "^1.0.0"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "esprima": {
            "version": "4.0.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima/-/esprima-4.0.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-eGuFFw7Upda+g4p+QHvnW0RyTX/SVeJBDM/gCtMARO0cLuT2HcEKnTPvhjV6aGeqrCB/sbNop0Kszm0jsaWU4A==",
            "dev": true
            },
            "extend-shallow": {
            "version": "2.0.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/extend-shallow/-/extend-shallow-2.0.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-Ua99YUrZqfYQ6huvu5idaxxWiQ8=",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "is-extendable": "^0.1.0"
            }
            },
            "js-yaml": {
            "version": "3.13.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml/-/js-yaml-3.13.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-YfbcO7jXDdyj0DGxYVSlSeQNHbD7XPWvrVWeVUujrQEoZzWJIRrCPoyk6kL6IAjAG2IolMK4T0hNUe0HOUs5Jw==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "argparse": "^1.0.7",
                "esprima": "^4.0.0"
            }
            },
            "kind-of": {
            "version": "5.1.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/kind-of/-/kind-of-5.1.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-NGEErnH6F2vUuXDh+OlbcKW7/wOcfdRHaZ7VWtqCztfHri/++YKmP51OdWeGPuqCOba6kk2OTe5d02VmTB80Pw==",
            "dev": true
            }
        },
        //...
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this vulnerability?